# Accept */* error in classic asp pages

Tags: error-handling, asp-classic, http-headers, bots

I had to move my site to a different server, so I believe it has to do with the different server setup.

I use a  Asp Classic.

I have a code to trap errors and email them to me.   All the pages load fine and have no issues form a client side.

I'm receiving the email with the following error message.  (this is on several of my pages).  The User-Agent naturally changes, and the Cookie info may or may not be blank.

```
At 1/1/2018 7:20:36 AM the following errors occurred on the page /entries.asp : Object required,  <br>Accept: */*
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSEQCBTBC=HAHPCOABKDGFLKDBPFDDCCDO
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; ds-66843412; Sgrunt|V109|1|S-66843412|dial; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
```

if I "search/render" the site as a bot, the page loads fine.  Below is the render header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSEQCBTBC=KBHPCOABJJAECLEENLJGOHMH; secure; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Mon, 01 Jan 2018 14:31:07 GMT
Content-Length: 8554

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I'm just trying to understand what could be throwing this error so I can fix it.

Comment: If you could show the code of entries.asp it might help.  "Object required" suggests that you are trying to use an object which hasn't been created

Comment: Is there a COM object you have installed on the old server, but the new server doesn't have (yet)? Look for SET statements to see what objects are used on the page giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Accepts` part of your error report might just be a bug in the email template (notice the BR tag?). The real meat of the problem is `Object required`.

As mentioned, this error occurs if you try to reference something as if it's an object, but it isn't. Either the object referenced by the variable doesn't exist, or ASP failed to instantiate the object (calling `CreateObject`) because **the required component isn't installed on the new server**.

You can either look for these calls manually in entries.asp or you can improve your email alerts by including the line number of the error if possible. For further help, I'd suggest you include the contents of your asp  file.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I will keep looking into this.   The pages uses mysql and classic asp.        I just can't replicate the error, when I load the page it loads fine. I have script written, so the errors get trapped and they see a nice error message.  The server it was on before, the company ran everything in house and did everything.  However since authorize.net changed ciphers and disabled some stuff, etc the server company didn't update and we had to move.  So I don't know what they had installed.

Comment: What's the method you use to trap ASP errors? Have you looked into setting up IIS failure trace logs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis